# SQL+ REGEXP + phone_number of all contacts having 5th digit of their phonenumber as '5' using REGEXP_SUBSTR()

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

Write a query to display the first_name, city, state and phone_number of all contacts having 5th digit of their phonenumber as '5'. Display the records in ascending order based on their first_name. 
Note:Use REGEXP_SUBSTR().

I need help on how to check for the 5th character to be 5 using regular expression
This what I have so far:

```
SELECT first_name, city, state, phone_number
FROM contact 
WHERE REGEXP_SUBSTR(phone_number, '^([[:digit:]]{4})([[:digit:]]{1})([[:digit:]]{4})',\1\2\3)
ORDDER BY first_name ASC;
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please take some time to read [ask].  This is not a private coding service.  If you want someone to help you, please show some effort and a [mcve]

Comment: why regexp_substr?  A regexp_like which aimed to match the pattern seems more appropriate here: `where regexp_like(phone_number, '^.{4}5')`

Comment: The assignment calls for using REGEXP_SUBSTR(). the editor seems to mark all other ways wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems here. First, you need to remove everything but digits from the phone number. Second, you need to determine if the fifth digit of the remaining numbers is '5'.

To remove all non-numeric characters you can use

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(PHONE_NUMBER, '[^0-9]', '')
```

For example, if your phone number is `(123)456-7890' the above will return`1234567890`.

Next, you need to determine if the fifth character of the above is the digit '5'. Now, the *easy* way to do it would be to use

```
SUBSTR(phone#, 5, 1) = '5'
```

but of course we can't do things the easy way. To do this using REGEXP_SUBSTR you'd use

```
'5' = REGEXP_SUBSTR(phone#, '^([0-9]{4})(5)([0-9]{5})$', 1, 1, 'i', 2)
```

So, putting the above together with your query we get

```
SELECT first_name, city, state, phone_number
  FROM contact 
  WHERE '5' = REGEXP_SUBSTR(REGEXP_REPLACE(PHONE_NUMBER, '[^0-9]', ''),
                              '^([0-9]{4})(5)([0-9]{5})$', 1, 1, 'i', 2)
  ORDER BY FIRST_NAME ASC
```

[SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d6b3b/2)

Best of luck.

Comment: Thanks a lot! this helps me understand Regular Expressions - It is quite confusing from the materials available online

Answer (score 0):

select first_name, city, state , phone_number from contact
where SUBSTR(phone_number, 5, 1) = '5' order by first_name asc;

Comment: What about using REGEXP_SUBSTR?